# postgres logging_collector sending to two directories simultaneously

Tags: postgresql, logging, postgres-9.6

In the course of testing logging for a postgres server we discovered logs were being sent to two different directories simultaneously.

The two locations were:

- `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_log/` (intended)
- `/var/log/postgresql/` (uninteded)

Settings changed in `postgresql.conf` prior:

```
logging_collector = on
log_destination = 'csvlog'
```

Settings in `postgresql.conf` not changed, but relevant:

```
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_truncate_on_rotation = off
```

I'm aware that both directories are standard for postgres logging, but sending to both simultaneously seems unusual.

We were testing logging for a day, and both sets of logs were created on that day.

Comment: Yes, but error messages end up in only one of them, right?

Comment: That was, indeed, my impression

Answer (score 3):

You must be using the Debian/Ubuntu packages for PostgreSQL.

The packagers have opted to *not* use PostgreSQL' `logging_collector`, but rather have the processes write the messages to standard error. These messages are then collected in a log file in `/var/log/postgresql`, and log rotation is applied to them (see the startup script for how they did it).

Now if you configure logging in PostgreSQL like you did, the log will be written to `log_directory`, but the startup process hasn't changed: it still creates a file in `/var/log/postgresql`, but now only the first few messages after the startup end there, then PostgreSQL switches to using its log file.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz!  What are the proper settings?

The only changes I made were `logging_collector = on` & `log_destination = 'csvlog'`.  With `logging_collector = off` we get logs in neither directory (as expected), and `= on` sends to both.  Should we set `log_directory = /var/log/postgresql/'` or does that just double things up?

Comment: With ´logging_collector = off`, the messages should end up in `/var/log/postgresql`. If you set it to `on`, the log will be written to `pg_log`. The file in `/var/log/postgresql` will still be created, but mostly empty. You can ignore that. Where so you want your log to end up?

Comment: So then it maybe our experience was something of an anomaly: We had (mostly) the same data going to both locations all day long.

Comment: That would be unexpected. But perhaps I have got something wrong - I don't have a Debian system nearby to test. Perhaps, without solving the mystery, you could disable `logging_collector` again and live with logs in `/var/log/postgresql`...

Comment: re 'That would be unexpected' -- That helps.  So it's looking like the logs were not being written in two locations "simultaneously" but rather "alternately" (based on reading the time stamps in the logs).  That aligns with what you are saying: Logging goes either to `/var/log/postgresql` or to `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_log` depending on whether `logging_collector` is set to `off` or `on`.  What's strange is that with the exception of yesterday, when we began testing the logging, no logs are ever being written in either location.  What might explain that?

Comment: Perhaps there was nothing to log.

Comment: Hah!  Yes!  I thought of that.  But I made sure there was.